# Exceptions handled in UseExceptionHandler are logged by Application Insights, but they shouldnt

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I initialize logging in program.cs:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And later I have some global exception handling in Startup.cs:

```
public static void ConfigureExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appError =>
        {
            appError.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            });
        });
    }
```

What I've noticed, code from my ITelemetryProcessor is executed before the one from app.UseExceptionHandler.

As the result, handled exceptions are being logged to Application Insights. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a decent workaround. I used custom middleware for changing response codes, so the exception doesn't pop up to insights, as long as it's handled in the middleware. Example:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}
```